Why oom_score of a cat command in terminal is less than my window manager?
For experimenting, I was seeing oom_score of some of processes in my computer. The oom_score of a cat command is 666 but oom_scoreof my window manager (which is i3) is 667.
If I understood correctly, this means that if the system goes out of memory, the OS would prefer to terminate my window manager rather than cat command invoked in a terminal to restore some memory space. Why this is the case? Based on which calculation oom score of cat is less than my window manager?
This is how I checked the OOM scores:
$ cat /proc/3446/oom_score
667
$ cat /proc/self/oom_score
666

Note that here 3446 is PID of i3 in my system.

Linux documentation on the /proc filesystem states in "Chapter 3: Per-process Parameters":

The badness heuristic assigns a value to each candidate task ranging from 0 (never kill) to 1000 (always kill) to determine which process is targeted. The units are roughly a proportion along that range of allowed memory the process may allocate from based on an estimation of its current memory and swap use. For example, if a task is using all allowed memory, its badness score will be 1000. If it is using half of its allowed memory, its score will be 500.

So, the score is calculated by taking into account the current memory and swap use of each of the two processes.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
